# Is there something like nodejs "should" module for python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm working on specific projects where I use python (3.4) scripts as a replacement for bash/batch scripting. I'm trying to make use of unittest module in order to get a quick and easy report.

I'm checking many different things with the script, taking requests and getting correct file from the server, unpacking .zip / .gz files, checking if there's a certain tree structure within the package, checking if there is a correct copyright on certain locations and so on.

For a different project I used NodeJS "Should" module, which was awesome to easily get the report:

```
it('Should return Tesla for that particular model', function(){
    myProps = beApi.getPropertiesSync(Tesla);
    myProps.contains('model', 'Tesla').should.be.equal(true, 'but was '+ myProps.get('model').getValue());
});
```

This is just one of examples.

Now the question, is there similar way to do it in Python?

Also, I am trying to make use of unittest module but it does not run (just yet) and I can't find a simple example that should work. This is what I have so far:

```
import fileinput
import zipfile
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def shall_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(input_doubled(5),25, "Something Wrong")

def main():
    print (input_doubled(5))
    unittest.main()    
    pass

def input_doubled(x):
    return x*x+2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my output is, sadly:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
25
```

Comment: test methods needs to start with `test` prefix. `def shall_fail` -> `def test_something`

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszRogalski, that resolved one issue straight away. :)  I've just seen it in the documentation, but after the examples...